# Using one if else statement to color progress bars in different contexts

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, parent

I’ve got some simple rolling progress bars, fed by a percentage number on the page (later this will come from a database), which change color and width dependent upon this number. Got them working nicely in one context, but on another page they need to use different colors. I’d like to use the same code for both, but I can’t get it to work.

In my statement, I'm saying I want percentage ranges to display the bar in their respective colors and at a width corresponding to that percentage.

The trouble comes in the last else statement, when I say that if the score is exactly 100 AND if the score's parent has the class '.report', color the bar gray. Tried everything I can think of and it either doesn't work or blows up the script entirely.

Still a freshie with JQuery/Javascript, but I think I love it... until I get stuck like this. Clearly I'm missing something fundamental here – probably in the parent() portion of the js, which I'm still shaky on, but what exactly is going wrong?

In my thinking, all the 100% bars here should be gray.

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
 
 $( '.score' ).each( function() {
        //get each score and apply width to progress bar
    var score = $( this ).text().trim();
  $( this ).closest( '.progbar' ).css('width', score + '%');
  
 var bar = $( this ).closest( '.progbar' );
 //apply colors to bar based on performance or progress
 var parent = $( '.score' ).closest( 'progbar' );
 
 if (score == 0){
  $( bar ).css('width', '0');
 } else if (score <= 100 && score >= 95){
  $( bar ).css( 'background-color', 'rgba( 53, 182, 103, .5)' );
  //console.log(parent);
 } else if (score <= 94 && score >= 80){
  $( bar ).css( 'background-color', 'rgba( 24, 133, 157, .5)' );
  //console.log(score);
 } else if (score <= 79 && score >= 60){
  $( bar ).css( 'background-color', 'rgba( 239, 149, 33, .5)' );
 } else if (score < 60){
  $( bar ).css( 'background-color', 'rgba( 198, 32, 55, .5)' );
 } else if ( score === 100 && score.parent().hasClass( '.report' ) ){//this is where it falls apart
  $( bar ).css( 'background-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)' );
  alert('hasClass');
 }
 });
});
```

```css
th{
    text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="report-table1 math">
                <!--<caption>
          Level 1 Reading to Common Core Standards
          </caption>-->
                
                <col>
                <col>
                <tr class="tabletop">
                  <th scope="col"><div>Standards in Strand </div></th>
                  <th scope="col"><div>Progress</div></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2" class="name sub2"><div>Common Core</div></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.A.1</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">100</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.A.2</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar"><span class="score">100</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.A.3</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">99</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.B.4</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">98</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.B.4.A</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">0</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.B.4.B</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">10</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.B.4.C</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">86</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.B.5</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">83</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.C.6</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">70</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
```

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/halfacre/08Lm3hvf/

Comment: Why do you think "all the bars here should be gray".  Only a few of those have 100%.

Comment: You are correct, I misspoke... edited to say all the 100% bars should be gray

Comment: Since you mentioned being able to change colors in different contexts, [here's some inspiration](http://jsfiddle.net/08Lm3hvf/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change (also see note at the end of my answer):

```
} else if (score <= 100 && score >= 95) {
```

To:

```
} else if (score < 100 && score >= 95) {
```

And:

```
} else if (score === 100 && score.parent().hasClass( '.report' ))
```

To:

```
} else if (score == 100 && $(this).parent().hasClass( 'report' ))
```

If I make those changes using your fiddle I get grey bars for 100%. The first change prevents the value of 100 being caught by the `score <= 100` condition, the second change allows JS to convert the arguments to the same type before comparing them, alternatively you could convert the score to an integer `score = parseInt(score)` before your series of if tests.

**Note:** If you want bars with a score of 100 to be green if a `.report` report class is not defined against the parent then you dont need to change the `} else if (score <= 100 && score >= 95) {` but rather move it so it's the last test in the series.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I changed to the `$( this)` statement and moved the first test to the end, but all the bars remain green. (Note that for reference I've removed the `.report` class from the second 100 score in the above example and the fiddle). Made your suggested changes to the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/halfacre/08Lm3hvf/5/ Can you see what I messed up?

Comment: Hi @MattKristiansen - in that fiddle all that needs changing is `} else if (score == 100 && $(this).parent().hasClass( '.report' )){` needs to be `} else if (score == 100 && $(this).parent().hasClass( 'report' )){` then it works :) - in the fiddle the class you're checking for still has a dot at the start.

Comment: That's the stuff! Just learned a number very important things from y'all. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems.

1. The last elseif statement will never be hit.  If score = 100 then it will be caught in this clause:  `else if (score <= 100 && score >= 95){`

Either move the last elseif above this one or change this one to `score < 100`.  My guess is moving it before this one makes more sense since you have an additional test that needs to be true `score.parent().hasClass( '.report' )`

2. `score` is a string.  So comparing it to 100 using the === operator will never be true.

Either change it to == or change the score variable to an integer using parseInt.  `score = parseInt(score, 10)`

3. `score` is a string.  So it has no parent.  `score.parent()` will return null (or undefined).

I think what you want here is `$( this ).parent()`

Comment: I think you're right about the `this`... The IDE I was using (which will remain nameless) kept badgering me about the `==` as opposed to `===`, and I backed down. That'll teach me

Comment: It's a good thing to use the === but you need to know what you are giving up when doing so.  '100' === 100 is false.  '100' == 100 is true.  Which is why parseInt was suggested.  parseInt('100', 10) === 100

Answer (score 1):

Change (score <= 100 && score >= 95) to (score < 100 && score >= 95).

Currently it is never reaching the condition ( score === 100 ) because score of 100 are caught at (score <= 100 && score >= 95)

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 issues:

- you check for `<= 100` in your second `if`, so the last one never matches, and
- you use `=== 100` in the last check, which requires `score` to be an int, and it is not (it's a string).

**UPDATE 1**

The final check for score 100 now sets the background color to green,
except if the parent has the `report` class. The test for this was:

`score.parent().hasClass( '.report')`

which has 2 issues: `score` is an integer, and `.report` is not a classname (but `report` is); `.report` is a CSS selector for the class `report`.

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
 
 $( '.score' ).each( function() {
        //get each score and apply width to progress bar
    var score = $( this ).text().trim();
  $( this ).closest( '.progbar' ).css('width', score + '%');
  
 var bar = $( this ).closest( '.progbar' );
 //apply colors to bar based on performance or progress
 var parent = $( '.score' ).closest( 'progbar' );
 
 if (score == 0){
  $( bar ).css('width', '0');
 } else if (score < 100 && score >= 95){
  $( bar ).css( 'background-color', 'rgba( 53, 182, 103, .5)' );
  //console.log(parent);
 } else if (score <= 94 && score >= 80){
  $( bar ).css( 'background-color', 'rgba( 24, 133, 157, .5)' );
  //console.log(score);
 } else if (score <= 79 && score >= 60){
  $( bar ).css( 'background-color', 'rgba( 239, 149, 33, .5)' );
 } else if (score < 60){
  $( bar ).css( 'background-color', 'rgba( 198, 32, 55, .5)' );
 } else if ( score == 100 ) {
        if ( $(this).parent().hasClass( 'report' ) )
    $( bar ).css( 'background-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)' );
        else
          $( bar ).css( 'background-color', 'rgba( 53, 182, 103, .5)' );
 }
 });
});
```

```css
th{
    text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="report-table1 math">
                <!--<caption>
          Level 1 Reading to Common Core Standards
          </caption>-->
                
                <col>
                <col>
                <tr class="tabletop">
                  <th scope="col"><div>Standards in Strand </div></th>
                  <th scope="col"><div>Progress</div></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2" class="name sub2"><div>Common Core</div></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.A.1</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">100</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.A.2</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">100</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.A.3</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">99</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.B.4</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">98</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.B.4.A</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">0</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.B.4.B</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">10</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.B.4.C</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">86</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.B.5</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">83</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.C.6</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">70</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
```

**UPDATE 2**

An alternate approach to make it possible to use different colors depending on the context, is to use classnames rather than harcode the color values in JavaScript.

For this I've used 4 classnames: `top` for 100%, `veryhigh` for 95+, `high` for 80+ and `medium` for 60+, and have the CSS define the colors for them.
This also allows us to override the `top` color in a `report`-class progbar easily without any JS code.

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
 
 $( '.score' ).each( function() {
        //get each score and apply width to progress bar
    var score = $( this ).text().trim();
  $( this ).closest( '.progbar' ).css('width', score + '%');
  
 var bar = $( this ).closest( '.progbar' );
 //apply colors to bar based on performance or progress
 var parent = $( '.score' ).closest( 'progbar' );
 
 if (score == 0){
  $( bar ).css('width', '0');
 } else if (score < 100 && score >= 95){
  $( this ).parent().addClass( 'veryhigh' );
  //console.log(parent);
 } else if (score <= 94 && score >= 80){
        $( this ).parent().addClass( 'high' );
 } else if (score <= 79 && score >= 60){
        $( this ).parent().addClass( 'medium' );
 } else if (score < 60){
        $( this ).parent().addClass( 'low' );  
 } else if ( score == 100 ) {
        $( this ).parent().addClass( 'top' );
 }
 });
});
```

```css
th{
    text-align:left;
}

.progbar.top.report {
  background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.progbar.veryhigh, .progbar.top {
  background-color: rgba( 53, 182, 103, .5);
}

.progbar.high {
  background-color: rgba( 24, 133, 157, .5);
}

.progbar.medium {
  background-color: rgba( 239, 149, 33, .5);
}

.progbar.low {
  background-color:rgba( 198, 32, 55, .5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="report-table1 math">
                <!--<caption>
          Level 1 Reading to Common Core Standards
          </caption>-->
                
                <col>
                <col>
                <tr class="tabletop">
                  <th scope="col"><div>Standards in Strand </div></th>
                  <th scope="col"><div>Progress</div></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2" class="name sub2"><div>Common Core</div></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.A.1</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">100</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.A.2</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">100</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.A.3</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">99</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.B.4</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">98</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.B.4.A</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">0</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.B.4.B</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">10</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.B.4.C</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">86</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.B.5</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">83</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="name tooltip"><div>• CCSS.MATH.CONTENT.K.CC.C.6</div></th>
                  <td class="report-table1 reading"><div class="progbar-wrap">
                      <div class="progbar report"><span class="score">70</span>%</div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
```

Comment: Here's the issue with this solution... when used in another view (not shown here), a score of 100% needs to remain green. Only in the context of this view (when the score's parent element will have a `'.report'` class) does a 100% score color the bar gray. I'd like to stay DRY if possible, and if I can accomplish this all in one statement, that would be awesome.

Comment: Allright, I'll modify the snippet to do that, and suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: Done. Hope you like the suggestion!